# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("1")

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I receive this error when ever i try to fetch data from json file. I don't know what to  next.
there are two errors i am receiving :
1 is : The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

and the second error that i am getting is:
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#43e62):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
to check what is the output i printed the array and this is i am getting:

```
   I/flutter (14372): {
   I/flutter (14372):     "questions": [
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "1": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "2": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw 2?"
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "3": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw 4?"
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "4": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "5": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "6": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
   I/flutter (14372):         }
   I/flutter (14372):     ],
   I/flutter (14372):     "options": [
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "1": [{
   I/flutter (14372):                 "a":"oo","b":"aaa","c":"www","d":"op"
   I/flutter (14372):             }]
   I/flutter (14372):         },
   I/flutter (14372):         {
   I/flutter (14372):             "2": [{"a":"ee","b":"ww","c":"ww","d"
```

this is the quizpage:

```
                class Getjson extends StatelessWidget {
              const Getjson({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                  future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                      .loadString("assets/files/dyslexQ.json"),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    //print(snapshot.data.toString());
                    Map<String, dynamic> mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                    if (mydata == null) {
                      return Scaffold(
                        body: Center(
                          child: Text("Loading"),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      print(snapshot.data.toString());
                      return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
                    }
                  },
                );
              }
            }
            
            // ignore: camel_case_types, must_be_immutable
            class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
              // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
              var mydata;
              quizpage({Key? key, required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);
            
              @override
              // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
              State<quizpage> createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
            }
            
            // ignore: camel_case_types
            class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
              // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
              var mydata;
              _quizpageState(this.mydata);
              void checkanswer(String k) {}
              Widget choicebutton(String k) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Colors.blue;
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      mydata[1]["1"][k],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                    splashColor: Colors.blue,
                    highlightColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 93, 152),
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                    minWidth: 200.0,
                    height: 45.0,
                    shape:
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                  ),
                );
              }
            
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
                    [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            mydata[1]["1"],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "GoogleFont"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 6,
                        // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
                        child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            choicebutton("a"),
                            choicebutton("b"),
                            choicebutton("c"),
                            choicebutton("d"),
                          ],
                        )),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "30",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 35.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
```

this is my json file:

```
{
                                    "questions": [
                                        {
                                            "1": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "2": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw 2?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "3": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw 4?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "4": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "5": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "6": "Match the shape by clicking on all the shapes that are the same as the one you just saw ?"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "options": [
                                        {
                                            "1": [{
                                                "a":"oo","b":"aaa","c":"www","d":"op"
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "2": [{"a":"ee","b":"ww","c":"ww","d":"qq"
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "3": [{"a":"qq","b":"ff","c":"ff","d":"ew"
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "4":[ {"a":"few","b":"e","c":"ew","d":"ew"
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "5":[ {"a":"few","b":"few","c":"ew","d":"ef"
                                            }]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "6":[ {"a":"wq","b":"wqqw","c":"qwdw","d":"qwqd"
                                            }]
                                
                                        }
                                        ]
                                }
```

Comment: the widget build method in the quizpage is giving me this error. please help i'm loosing my mind here

Answer (score 0):

1. jsonDecode('') and not json.Decode('')
2. create a main() to run your stateless widget. I hope this code solves your problem.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Getjson());
}

class Getjson extends StatelessWidget {
  const Getjson({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
          .loadString("assets/files/dyslexQ.json"),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //print(snapshot.data.toString());
        Map<String, dynamic> mydata = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString());
        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        if (mydata == null) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Loading"),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          print(snapshot.data.toString());
          return QuizPage(mydata: mydata);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

// ignore: camel_case_types, must_be_immutable
class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var mydata;
  QuizPage({Key? key, required this.mydata}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
  State<QuizPage> createState() => _QuizPageState(mydata);
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var mydata;
  _QuizPageState(this.mydata);
  void checkAnswer(String k) {}
  Widget choiceButton(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Colors.blue;
        },
        child: Text(
          mydata[1]["1"][k],
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        splashColor: Colors.blue,
        highlightColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 93, 152),
        color: Colors.cyan,
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 45.0,
        shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Text(
                mydata[1]["1"],
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "GoogleFont"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
            child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    choiceButton("a"),
                    choiceButton("b"),
                    choiceButton("c"),
                    choiceButton("d"),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  "30",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: its still giving me this error : The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("1")       error line : mydata[1]["1"],    (line number 105 in quizpage)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the state of the Future because you attempted to use `snapshot.data` without checking it's null or not

```
 if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
     // Wait the future, data is not ready yet...   
     // SizedBox.shrink(); is just for sampling, fit return statement by your purpose
     return SizedBox.shrink();
 } else {
    if(snapshot.hasError){
        // Did you know ? Something bad happened...
        return SizedBox.shrink();
    } else {
        // All is well! Use me
        Map<String, dynamic> mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: i tried your way but it is still giving me this error :       The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("1")              the line that is showing me the error is :   mydata[1]["1"],(line number 105 in quizpage)